# Rendering mRSS feed in Chrome using jsapi

Tags: google-chrome, rss, jsapi

Using google feed api to parse and render a mRSS feed.
I am having issue in chrome as it doesn't show the content...
**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/photous/guafh1ab/)**

Any idea why is that?...

```
function initialize() {
    var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://www.wdcdn.net/rss/presentation/library/client/robotrepair/id/a51a000c78e6997a1b7d422247cad813");
    feed.setNumEntries(99);
    feed.load(function(result) {
        if (!result.error) {
            var container = document.getElementById("feed");
            for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
                var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
                var img = document.createElement("img");
                if (entry.mediaGroups) {
                    var imgSrc = entry.mediaGroups[0].contents[0].thumbnails[0].url;
                    img.setAttribute("src", imgSrc);
                    container.appendChild(img);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: the fiddle seems to work for me, I can see the images

Comment: Thanks for your answer and now can you see it?... Same link. I think they clear the cache of the feed every 10 hours... It was working for a while and is working in incognito mode but it is not working for me at the moment... Could it be a this [socket issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=324653) ?

Comment: Yes, I can see the images. I'm using Chrome 41.0.2272.118 on OSX